# JSP - print a text in all heading tags using for loop

Tags: jsp

I supposed to print "hello" 6 times in JSP. Each output should be in an  tag, where the ? gets higher each time through the loop. But I only get the same size of "hello" 6 times. How to print it in all different heading tags like  through ?

```
<body>
    <%            
        for (int a=1; a<=6; a++) {
            %> <h <%= a %> > <% out.println("hello"); %> </h <%= a %> > <%
        }
    %>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just view the resulting html (go to view source - from your web browser) - it'll give you the idea - what's wrong..

what you are getting is

```
 <h 1> hello</h 1>
```

what you need is (notice the spaces between h and the number)

```
<h1>hello</h1>
```